# Refresh QLCDNumber and implementing generic function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm doing some preliminary tests before I start programming the GUI I need with pyqt5, and today I found a couple of things that I haven't been able to solve.

My code is the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(398, 398)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 131, 61))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 131, 61))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 40, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.lcdNumber_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber_2.setObjectName("lcdNumber_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 398, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.number = 0
        self.number_2 = 0
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.number)
        self.lcdNumber_2.display(self.number_2)


        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.change_number)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


    def change_number(self):
        ip = int(self.lineEdit.text())

        if ip > self.number:
            count = 1
        elif ip < self.number:
            count = -1
        else:
            count = 0

        while self.number != ip :
            self.number += count
            self.lcdNumber.display(self.number)
            time.sleep(1)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see I have two QLineEdit boxes and two QLCDNumber for displaying the number that I write in the corresponding QLineEdit.

**Problem 1**

I'm able to display the number in the QLCDNumber with the following code:

```
self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.change_number)

...

def change_number(self):
    self.lcdNumber.display(int(self.lineEdit.text()))
```

However, if I want to change the displayed number one by one with a certain time delay, my code doesn't work as I expect.

For example, if the current number is 0 and I type 10 in the QLineEdit, the program freezes for 10 seconds and then the number 10 is displayed on the QLCDNumber, while I would expect it to be updated second by second. I really can't figure out where the problem is.

**Problem 2**

I have two QLineEdit and two QLCDNumber, and it doesn't make much sense to write two different functions change_number.
However, I can't find a way for writing a generic function that takes as an input which QLCDNumber will be updated and which QLineEdit will be the input.
In pseudocode, it would be something like this:

```
self.LINEEDIT_NAME.returnPressed.connect(self.change_number(LINEEDIT_NAME,QLCD_NAME))

...

def change_number(self,LINEEDIT_NAME,QLCD_NAME):
    ip = int(self.LINEEDIT_NAME.text())

    if ip > self.number:
        count = 1
    elif ip < self.number:
        count = -1
    else:
        count = 0

    while self.number != ip :
        self.number += count
        self.QLCD_NAME.display(self.number)
        time.sleep(1)
```

but I'm not able to use the LINEEDIT_NAME and QLCD_NAME as variables of the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep()` is a task that blocks the `PyQt` loop so it is not recommended to use it, the task can easily be substituted with a `QTimer`.

To facilitate the work we will create a class that inherits from `QLCDNumber` and that uses a `QTimer` to update the values

**TimerLCDNumber.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class TimerLCDNumber(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        self.finished = self.value()

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.finished = value
        self.timer.start()

    def onTimeout(self):
        current = self.value()
        if self.finished != current:
            count  = 1 if self.finished > current else -1
            self.display(current + count)
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
```

This task can be promoted through Qt Designer or simply change, assuming that the file generated by Qt Designer is called design.py:

**design.py**

```
self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
self.lcdNumber_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
```

to:

```
self.lcdNumber = TimerLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
self.lcdNumber_2 = TimerLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
```

In addition, the `TimerLCDNumber` class must be imported:

```
from TimerLCDNumber import TimerLCDNumber
```

It is advisable to separate the design from the logic so a new file called main.py is created that imports the design class and implements the logic:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from design import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.lcdNumber.setValue(int(self.lineEdit.text())))
        self.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.lcdNumber_2.setValue(int(self.lineEdit_2.text())))
        self.lcdNumber.display(0)
        self.lcdNumber_2.display(0) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At the end in our folder we must have the following structure:

```
.
├── design.py
├── main.py
└── TimerLCDNumber.py
```

A possible solution for the second question is to use the lambda functions:

**first option:**

```
self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.lcdNumber.setValue(int(self.lineEdit.text())))
self.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.lcdNumber_2.setValue(int(self.lineEdit_2.text())))
```

**second option:**

```
    self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: change_number(self.lineEdit, self.lcdNumber))
    self.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(lambda: change_number(self.lineEdit_2, self.lcdNumber_2))


def change_number(self,LINEEDIT_NAME,QLCD_NAME):
    QLCD_NAME.setValue(int(LINEEDIT_NAME.text()))
```

The complete code can be found at the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/178d11a85b8cf0c973cdae8204b2c9cb).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the code!

I'm also surprised by something that I wasn't expecting: I wanted to add multithreading to this GUI so that the two counters LCDNumber would have changed at the same time. However, I noticed that with your code this is already implemented.
Is this a feature of pyqt itself?

Comment: PyQt implements an infinite loop that checks if any signal of any of its objects is emitted, so when it does it will call the appropriate slot. So it is advisable to use the signals and slots. I only recommend using threads when the task consumes a lot of resources and in your case it is not, but PyQt also foresees those cases so there is usually a better solution than threads.